# ipod touch jailbreaking on linux

Tags: linux, ipod-touch, jailbreak

Santa brought me an iPod Touch (OS v3.1.2, Model MC series). I was wondering if it is possible to jailbreak it through a Linux machine (Ubuntu Karmic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jailbreaking is not possible natively on Linux. You can setup a VM under Linux and try that option but better off doing it in Windows or a Mac

Answer (score 1):

No. blackra1n works on Windows and Mac, while PwnageTool is Mac only.